# Add Questions/Day to the Site Stats sidebar of beta sites

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, beta-phase

Currently on beta sites, the Site Stats sidebar reports:

- questions
- answers
- % answered
- users
- visitors/day

Now that [Questions per Day is an important indicator of readiness for graduation](/q/257614/148099), can we add that metric to the Site Stats sidebar?  That information is available by visiting Area 51, but it would be nice to have the statistic prominently visible.

Answer (score 5):

This is still an issue for our newer users who don't know the site and network's history. For example this question asking what it would take for Bricks to graduate so that we can have a more branded experience:

> [Criteria for losing "beta" status](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/56)

This also asks about the Area 51 stats, and my answer explains the questions/day stat.

As the Site Stats module only appears on Beta sites, it would make sense for it to show the most important stat that is  considered for site graduation:

[image: Site Stats]

Comment: If you agree, upvote the question. There's no need to post that as an answer.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I'd agree (and I have done so), but the original request was some 3 years ago, so upvoting alone isn't going to raise much awareness of the request amongst the 22k other [tag:feature-request] ;)

Comment: True, but that's where bounties are for :)

Comment: @Glorfindel According to [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398), a bounty isn't an effective way to get official SE attention for feature requests, while an answer is. Note, however, that an answer should add to the request, not merely be redundant to it.

Comment: Cheers for digging that out sonic. I thought this was slightly better than just "bump" or making a non-visible change to the question, and as I've not got 2k rep here I can't edit the question without review anyway. I'll happily edit my picture into the question if that's a better "bump" ;)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I've now upvoted your answer.  As a Beta mod that's a stat I'd like to see at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/ too.