# Reputation change counter doesn't take into account deleted downvotes

Tags: support, reputation

The network-wide counter on the top displayed the correct +9 value, but the activity page showed 8:
[image: reputation tab screenshot]

Comment: If you want to try and get the duplicate target question answered, see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).