# Site does not exist... yet page has a weird text alignment

Tags: bug, design

The site [a.stackexchange.com](http://a.stackexchange.com/) doesn't exist. The error page for this looks bad:

[image]

The top text is duplicated, and the logo is misplaced.

---

Chrome 67.0.3396.99 and Safari Version 12.0 (14606.1.22.2) on macOS 10.14.

Comment: No repro, [that's what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGev.png). Try: 1) CTRL+F5. 2) Clear cache. 3) Disable userscripts. 4) Use other browser. (And as with all design bugs, please include what browser/OS you have, as many times it's browser specific.)

Comment: To help get attention for the duplicate target, you can follow the tips at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without)