# "You've earned (badge)" panel layouts are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, badge-progress

When I visit [my activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) I see this:

[image: two sections on the page have their appearance broken]

- The "Congratulations! You've earned (badge)" section has dropped down completely beneath the tabs under it.
- The "You've earned a new privilege!" section has a gap at the bottom:

  [image: small space inside the box beneath the button]

Shog9 says in comments how to reproduce this:

> Gotta have earned a badge, not dismissed the notification, and be looking at your own profile.

Comment: cannot reproduce on chrome

Comment: I have reproduced on Chrome 69 on Windows 8.1. Gotta have earned a badge, not dismissed the notification, and be looking at your own profile.

Comment: This was also reported (or something similar) on ELU: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11758/121385

Comment: Reproduced, Windows 10, Firefox 62.0.2. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWyVb.png). Hovering over the tabs show the layer behind.

Comment: I sincerely hope that you find your answer.

Comment: OH NO! Same problem with me now: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84KKM.jpg.

Comment: also reported at MSO: [Buggy UI when a badge is earned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374744/839601)

Comment: Reproduced on Electronics and Coffee. Fairly sure it's on all SE sites. [Report here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316696/badge-tracker-out-of-whack).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog Please don't remove tags to “ensure space for status tag”. Removing a tag for this reason is not appropriate or necessary and causes harm. Admins are perfectly capable themselves of removing a tag to make room if and when they need to add a status tag, and until that point if a fifth tag is relevant its presence will aid in discovery.

Comment: Now this is appearing on all of the sites every time I earn a badge

Comment: @PotatoLatte I think it is common to every site with the new layout.

Comment: This is being reported every other day (and probably equally often on all the individual meta sites). Why is there no reaction at all since weeks? Does this need to be posted on twitter?

Comment: @fontgeologist I imagine it's noticed but a bit further down on priorities than current work. It's not an overwhelming problem after all, just a highly noticeable one.

Comment: @doppelgreener I understand that this is not top priority, but they could at least acknowledge that this is a bug by adding a status tag. That it will take ages until fixed is to be expected...

Comment: @fontgeologist It was acknowledged in the second comment saying that they could reproduce it from their end. There exists a status tag for that - [tag:status-reproduced] - but presumably they forgot to add it. (But they did leave a comment.)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog the comment said: "Why is there no reaction at all since weeks?" not, nobody has said a word. In fact, since September 28 there has been no further reaction. So fontgeologist is quite right. Allow me to express myself in Italian, "CoC, il nuovo design, i bug, il HNQ, …insomma c'é un gran bel casino" It's like witnessing the fall of a once great empire.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There *was* a reaction, in the second comment. Two CMs commented on this shortly after this was posted. They just didn't add the [tag:status-reproduced] tag for some reason.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog **“since [sic] weeks”** he's saying that there has been no further comments, no update, no other form of communication. I would expect at least a proper answer by a community manager or mod, explaining that the bug will take time to fix. Have you seen the number of times this bug has been reported? See the linked questions column.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, that's a good point. But it's really not worth being impatient about these things; they usually put it down in their internal bug tracker and get to it when higher-priority issues are taken care of. If you want to try and get them to expedite something, you can follow the tips at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398), but it's up to them to decide what to do.

Comment: Also reported on physics SE: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10868/profile-activity-layout-issue

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed (at least on a couple of sites I've checked, where I had the problem) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug has been fixed somewhere between October 19<sup>th</sup> 2018 when it was marked as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) by Catija (see revisions) and October 27<sup>th</sup> 2018 when Glorfindel [said in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316061/youve-earned-badge-panel-layouts-are-broken#comment1040566_316061) that it's working fine.