# The Stack Exchange app does not let me log in with my Google account and displays an error

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-exchange, login

I downloaded the Stack Exchange app on my secondary phone (Android 6.0) and installed it. I tried to log in with my Google account. However, an error occurred.

I tried the next day on my main phone (Android 5.1) and got the exact same error.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error from my main phone]

The version is the latest that is on the Play Store (latest update: 30 June 2017).

I think that the error happens because the app's code is no longer compatible with Google's recent Play Services update.

I sent an e-mail to the Stack Exchange developers about this (androidapp@stackexchange.com), however I did not get any response. So I thought that I would get a faster response here.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's likely that due to the lack of maintenance to the app, that email inbox is no longer being checked. But for tips on how to get the original request addressed, please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog So, that leaves mobile users (Android & iOS) with no update?

Comment: Yep, the mobile apps aren't being maintained anymore.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Too bad... RIP Mobile Stack Exchange.

Comment: To their favor, I'd say SE spends tons of resources on the responsive design these days, which means ideally you'll get a better experience by simply visiting the sites with a mobile browser. It's not ready yet, but will be at some point.