# Is there a defined process to communicate with Stack Overflow Inc?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago I asked [how to fix triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376364/how-to-fix-triage) on SO META.

Last week, then put a comment under a response of [Joe Friend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/354333/joe-friend) asking if he could comment on that. No response.

So, in the end, I accepted that answer on SO META that boils down to "I asked the same thing over a year ago, and nothing happens". (that other question btw saw 100 upvotes and has 5000 views)

In that sense, it *feels* like: even a SO META question with 150+ votes gets simply ignored by Stackoverflow Inc. And I see similar complaints all over the place: people aren't happy with how their input is treated (ignored) constantly.

Thus:

- does SO Inc. have a real "process" to track, assess and prioritize community requests?
- or is it a fair statement to say that although the community is providing all the content that attracts users and clicks here has no *real* way of influencing anything?

Comment: _“no real way of influencing anything”_ — see [these 11,465 questions tagged with “status-completed”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D+is%3Aq) on MSE and [these 2,951 results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D+is%3Aq) on MSO.

Comment: @Xufox I see your 11465 completed posts and raise you [18,199 ignored posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+-%5Bstatus-*%5D+is%3Aq+).

Comment: @Xufox most are old minor bug reports posted back in Jeff days when the dev team actually fixed bugs reported here. Most new bugs are marked completed as result on indirect changes they make, that fix bugs as a side effect, not as result of reporting it. (So someone flags the bug, and after few months when SE staff see the flag they mark it as completed)

Comment: You got a pretty nice response from Shog the day after you asked the question explaining the broader concerns.

Comment: And I replied to that. But the fact that even proposals for the slightest changes to make something stupid a bit less terrible sit there for years speaks by itself.

Comment: To get old requests that haven't already received a staff response responded to, you can follow the directions at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Well, the requests I am talking about have upvotes. Plenty of them. They are written in reasonable ways. I don't see much else besides sending an email to the SO team directly in your link...

Comment: Well, TBH I'd just write that in. But it would be downvoted and seem like a rant. So I did an excellent job of couching it. :)