# Make a gold badge to encourage more tag wiki edits

Tags: feature-request, badges, tag-wiki

My main site is [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). I'm not sure how many tag wikis I've edited, but probably not many more than it took to get the shiny silver [Research Assistant](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/99/research-assistant) badge for editing 50 tag wikis that's also been earned by twelve other users on our site.

Good tag wikis are important and I know I should be writing them, but inevitably I put it off in favour of some other work... a badge would make the difference between getting round to it and not getting round to it.

I know writing and improving tag wikis is a slog and most people won't do it even though there are badges, but that's ok. A site only needs a few <strike>badge-pursuers</strike> enthusiastic wiki-makers to make a big difference.

So I think there should be a gold badge for making, say, 200 tag wiki edits. It could be called Doctorate (because of the research required), for example.

Comment: but @Glorfindel there's no answer... and that was many years ago and suggests 2 different things. It doesn't even have a [status]... forgotten post!

Comment: The idea is essentially the same, however. To try and get attention for that request, you can follow the guidelines at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog thanks - that's a good question, but your answer just has crumbs. I already upvoted that post, and there's no way I'm going to bother SE about it directly, so I'm just going to sigh sadly and give up

Comment: Note that the only reason I included that "last resort" bit in there is because Tim Post said it's OK to contact the team for things like these. There's no problem in doing so, in my opinion.

Comment: You can put a 50 rep bounty in that question; so to give it more visibility. I spent 600 rep in it in the past; don’t have the “money” right now.

Comment: @AndreSilva well, firstly I'm not interested in the badge for excerpts part of it (I'm just proposing one clear thing) and secondly Sonic's answer says bounties are not useful for drawing "official" attention to forgotten FRs :(

Comment: There is one message in the bounty dialog that is exactly for that (official attention), but agree it does not work frequently. You can add your question as an answer there too. Or edit your question to explain how it is different than the other and why you think it should be reopened.