# Italic on heavily downvoted answer is not gray

Tags: bug, answers, down-votes

https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/55322/14341

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes it is a bug!

Comment: Possibly mobile-only. Repro'd in Chrome on Android, no repro in Chrome on Linux.

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate. (Edit: so it is)

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ I don't think it's fair to close a question if the older question never received an answer and was posted 4 and a half years ago. We cannot tell the OP that their question has been asked *and* answered if only the first part is true.

Comment: @Mari-LouA but it increases the chance of receiving answers?

Comment: What does? By closing this question? Your question *was* more likely to receive some attention if *had been* upvoted and left open than if is closed as a duplicate of a question that attracted a grand total of 69 views in less than five years. P.S I see you have voted to close your own question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA the other question will be pumped to the front page, won't it?

Comment: Why should it be *b*umped? A question is bumped to the front page if someone posts a new answer or if a post is edited. Now no one can post an answer on this question and some users will believe that the older question has one or more answers, so they will hardly be motivated to visit it either.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks for the correction. Are you sure that the only way for a question to be bumped is when someone pasts a new answer or it is edited? How about voting? If the other question is not bumped, then it's kind of weird to me

Comment: You can test your theory easily. Upvote any question that is older than 6 months and see if it appears on the front page. You're not a newcomer Ooker, you should already know this stuff.

Comment: maybe you can get some ideas here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without Good luck!

Comment: @Mari-LouA well I actually don't know this, and has assumed that the question would be also bumped by voting or when other questions are link to it by duplication