# Including a quick drop-down list of possible changes in edit summary

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary

More often than not, people edit other's questions to rephrase the question for clarity, fixing grammar, corrections of spellings, adding MathJax, reformatting to improve readability, removing pictures and so on. Of course, there could be other uncommon reasons for editing.

Instead of typing the common reasons every time an edit has been suggested, why don't the developers include a dropdown list of possible 5-6 reasons along with an option for 'others' that opens up a blank space to type specific reason?

For the edit to be even submitted, you have to type 10 character summary. I mean it isn't like it takes up a lot of time, but selecting an option for common purposes seems easier.

Comment: The answer provided in that question mentions this: "In most cases there is no important "why", you just fixed some problems with the post and there is no reason to put anything in the revision comment." However, the edit won't be submitted if you do not type 10 characters!

Comment: This question has been asked before, yes. But there is no satisfying answer. See my comment above. Please revoke the duplicate mark.

Comment: Users with binding edit privileges aren't subject to the 10+ character requirement (summaries like "added [x] characters in body" are auto-generated); I think that users without that privilege should be required to explain their own edits so that users understand their meaning (a significant proportion of the time, reviewers don't).

Comment: It's a valid practice to close questions as duplicates if the same feature has been proposed, but hasn't received an official response. To help get attention for the original request, you can follow the guidelines at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Alright. When does one obtain editing privileges?

Comment: At [2,000 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).