# Search on all sites: tag links lead to the 404 link not found page

Tags: bug, tags, search, hyperlinks, 404-not-found

Searching on all sites, e.g., https://stackexchange.com/search?q=dokuwiki, gives me a list of questions with tag links.

Clicking one of the tag links, e.g., https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dokuwiki leads to the 404 page-not-found page. The problem is obvious from the form of the link: It should contain the specific site instead of the generic site stackexchange.com.

Comment: P.S. self-marked as a duplicate because after writing the older question turned up. I let it stand here to increase the "surface" of the question.

Comment: Posting a duplicate is usually *not* an effective way to ensure that your question receives an official response. For better ways, see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is defintiley intersting and worth reading. However, with "increasing the surface" I just mean that the original question can be found faster in a search.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But generally I find it better to just make edits. That dupes add signposts for searchability is more of an effect rather than a cause.