# How does one request an updated header image for a particular site?

Tags: support, design, images

This question is about a minor change to a header image on the Mathematica Stack Exchange site.

For background information, see:

1. [Ask the Community: Should we add "Wolfram Language" to our site's header image?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2461/ask-the-community-should-we-add-wolfram-language-to-our-sites-header-image)
2. [Site Logo Text: Mathematica and XXX. Which wording exactly?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/site-logo-text-mathematica-and-xxx-which-wording-exactly)
3. [New Site Logo: Final versions](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2477/new-site-logo-final-versions)

It's hard to tell what the status of a request to Stack Exchange is. For a while it looked like this image changeover was imminent. Then things have gone very quiet (since the end of May).

My questions:

1. What is the process for getting (minor) changes like these completed?
2. What expectations on timelines should one have (days, weeks, months, years)?
3. Have other people here had success with making changes like this and, if so, do you have any advise on how to complete this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without). See Monica Cellio's answer for advice on how to get site-specific changes implemented.

Comment: ok, thanks for the insights.