# Inline Code Editor Unusable in Chrome

Tags: support, editor, stack-snippets

From what I've read, this is the proper place for this thing. I first thought [tweeting you](https://twitter.com/Mswilson4040/status/1153469438525489152) would get an answer, but I guess not.

On Stack Overflow, when you answer/ask a question, you have the option insert a JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet. I think there is a bug as the code editor is very slow to pick up keystrokes, clicks, or any other event. I thought it may be a browser extension, but I tried running stackoverflow.com in an incognito window and it's still crazy slow.

The easiest way to reproduce the problem:

1. Open up Chrome
2. Add a snippet to an answer/question
3. Note how slow it is to open the code editor dialog
4. Start typing in the code editor (any HTML/JavaScript/CSS content). Note how slow it is to pick up your key presses
5. Run your snippet. See how clicking the button takes a couple of seconds to be even picked up and processed.
6. Save the snippet to your post. Note how long/glitchy it is as it's saving it and the closing of the editor.

I can reproduce this on three different computers (all macs). This is also not a network issue as all other pages and features within Stack Overflow perform as expected. Not to mention, I can reproduce this at work and at home on a consistent basis

[image]

Appears to work fine with Firefox, but it's unusable in Chrome. Seems like it's been this way for awhile. I have a video/GIF demonstrating the issue, but it's too big to be uploaded here.

Comment: The uploader in chat has a higher (but unknown) file size limit. Try uploading your image there and embed it here.

Comment: I don't know how to access chat. I only see that option pop-up when the comment thread gets really busy.

Comment: Click the gray Stack Exchange logo on the top right corner, and click on "chat".

Comment: that perceived slowness is reported before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386074/issue-with-code-snippet-lagging

Comment: Nice. Glad someone else can reproduce it. Looks like they're on a mac as well...

Comment: Is there a way to get in contact with someone at Stack Overflow to show them these two threads? Seems like there's an issue to fix here...

Comment: Please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: Thanks @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. I tried the contact form. I mentioned both articles in the form. Hopefully it gets fixed!