# How can I find out the name of user who has asked the most questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I would like to know who has asked the most number of questions and how many they asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer ([SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)) can answer such questions for you. Fortunately someone's [already written such a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1289636/users-with-most-questions).

In fact [quite a lot of people did](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=most+questions) so you can pick any of those queries that work for you and run them.

The query itself would look something like this...

```
SELECT
  u.Id, u.DisplayName, COUNT(*) AS NumPosts
FROM Posts p
  INNER JOIN Users u ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
WHERE
  p.PostTypeId = 1
GROUP BY U.Id, U.DisplayName
ORDER BY NumPosts DESC
```