# Please add a delay to the tag-badge tooltips in closed post notices

Tags: feature-request, design, tooltips

The tooltips for tag badges in closed post notices come up too fast.  Hovering or even just passing over the ["discussion" tag badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/discussion) in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354780/how-can-i-find-out-the-name-of-user-who-has-asked-the-most-questions-on-stack-ov) post brings up the tooltip way too quickly - compare it to hovering/rolling over an upvote tooltip, for example.

From [Adam Lear's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349530/please-add-a-delay-to-the-hover-tooltips/353319#353319) to the post, [Please add a delay to the hover tooltips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349530/please-add-a-delay-to-the-hover-tooltips):

> We've added a 300ms delay on all tooltips. Thought about making it configurable per tooltip, but ultimately landed on consistency being more important.

But the 300ms pause doesn't apply to these tooltips, apparently.  It would be great if it did.

---

**UPDATE**

It also happens with the rollover tooltips in the timelines of posts closed by a user with a tag badge, like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/354780/timeline) one, for example.

Comment: Worth to mention that other custom tooltips/rollovers e.g. the tag popup are fine and with a proper delay.