# What is the point of redirecting from the Flag dialog to the Close dialog if you do not have any close votes left?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flag-dialog

This post is related to a post that I did on the Spanish SO Meta, but a Moderator told me that they are limited and that he did not know what information or answer to give me:

[Cual es la gracia de pasarte de la Interface de Reporte a la de Cierre si no tienes votos de Cierre Vigentes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5311/cual-es-la-gracia-de-pasarte-de-la-interface-de-reporte-a-la-de-cierre-si-no-tie)

**the content or translation is as follows:**

I was checking this post: [No puedo cargar datos cuando subo archivos a godaddy, en local si cargan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/498082/no-puedo-cargar-datos-cuando-subo-archivos-a-godaddy-en-local-si-cargan)

and I agree that this post is missing Details; As I know that I no longer have Close votes for today, I am about to raise a flag (using the flag button) and that other users who moderate are also those who make the closing vote:

Upon entering the flagging interface, I see that I have 56 flags left:

[image: flag dialog with 56 remaining flags]

clicking on **Needs Improvements (Necesita Mejoras)** sends me to the closing interface:

[image: close dialog with 0 remaining votes]

***So it sends me to a dialog with no way out and without being able to do anything, is this correct?***

In this case the system should let me flag. Waiting 3 hours to have close  votes does not help the community. Or it is 56 or it is 20 or it is 0. But let me do something.

**Update:**

I do not agree that this post has been closed, because the original post is more than 5 years old and it has not been attended by someone from the staff of the site other than in that post; no apparent relevant solution is offered to be easily implemented.

Comment: @bobble It seems to me that it is not a duplicate; since it says nothing about how to fix it; Although the publication looks like the publication does not have a solution or an accepted answer ... and it is from 5 years ago; I imagine a lot of things have changed.

Comment: The proposal contained in it is the exact same as your line "In this case the system should let me flag".

Comment: ok, but this was talked about 5 years ago and I have not had any relevance; how can this be brought back to the dialogue table ... that POST doesn't even appear in my search XD

Comment: [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398/1017231)

Comment: If you don't think this question should have been closed, then why did you vote for it to be closed?

Comment: because I don't have time to fight with the network moderators ... to support this post ... they suggested closing it, who am I to question it ... I will assume they are right even if I don't share their opinion ... I will return to my work, thanks for the comments.