# Inline code formatting tries to escape the page!

Tags: bug, code-formatting, information-display, inline-code

I was going through the First Questions review queue, and was given [this review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1202476). I don't think the inline code block should render like that. Even though the OP should have used a code block, I don't really think that going all the way off the page is really the correct action for long inline code blocks.

Can the style of inline code please be changed to limit the grey background of the inline code to where the question body is, as opposed to the entire right side of the page?
[image: Screenshot of Ask Ubuntu]
[image: Screenshot of poorly formatted review]

Comment: Related: [Comment Overflow?](/q/361250/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Appears to be the same issue, but this is about posts/reviews more than comments, so I don't think it's a dupe, even though (I think) the root cause is the same.

Comment: I’ve seen this issue reported multiple times. I’m currently searching for a duplicate target.

Comment: There it is: [Inline code with lot of spaces overflow on the right side](/q/347630/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon That is the same issue, but... *it wasn't fixed!*

Comment: I know. Duplicate closure is appropriate in these cases. We don’t need to create a new post all the time for every unresolved issue if it’s already a _known_ issue. If you’re worried about the “already has answers here” wording or the “Does this answer your question” wording, this is a separate issue: [New duplicate automatic comment makes literally zero sense when voting to close as a duplicate of an unanswered question](/q/340009/289905). Apart from that, as usual, this appears to be a Chrome-specific bug. It looks fine on Firefox.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Fair enough, I've accepted that it's a dupe. Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306397/1017231)